# Ubuntu Deleted /var/logs

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, logging

Is there a way to restore `/var/log` ? I don't really care about past logs I at least need the dir structure so programs can write to their logs.

For example I went to start apache and it failed because it could not write `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

I ran `sudo mkdir /var/log/apache2` tried again and everything worked fine.